# Magento product upload through csv

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I downloaded the csv file using export in magento. Then i changed one quantity of a product and uploaded it back using import-> append complex data
I face an issue now after upload...
The quantity of first product is applied to all products.
does anyone know why?

Comment: this also changed my images also